Can exponentiated coefficients in multinominal logistic regression (with softmax normalization) be interpreted as odds ratios?
Exponentiated logistic regression coefficients are interpreted as odds ratios. Does this still hold in multinominal logistic regression, where softmax is typically used to normalize probabilities to ensure they sum up to 1?
This is, for example, performed by this scikit-learn multinominal (multiclass) problems. There, to obtain the same probability estimate  as scikit-learn (predict_proba), one has to do
import numpy as np
logits = np.dot(test, coef_.T) + intercept_
exp_logits = np.exp(logits)
probabilities = exp_logits / np.sum(exp_logits) # (!!) softmax
print(probabilities)

Since logits are subject to softmax before they are used to compute the probability, I am wondering if just exponentiating the coefficients (np.exp(model.coef_)) can be directly interpreted as odds ratios, given that the softmax transformation is not accounted for in this step. However, softmax has a possibly strong effect on the resulting probabilities when all variables are accounted for.
The resulting probabilities without the application of softmax are quite different:
probability_no_softmax = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-logits))

Even after normalization to 1:
probability_no_softmax/np.sum(probability_no_softmax)

If logistic regression coefficients for multinominal models cannot be directly interpreted as odds ratios, how to incorporate the softmax into the intepretation of the coefficients?
Data for complete reproducible examples:
import numpy as np
test = np.array([[50,10000,1000]])
coef_= np.array([[-1.02166294e-02,-2.32232541e-05,1.13787899e-03],  [ 5.04602305e-03,-2.29265186e-04,7.62774637e-04],  [ 8.26318650e-03,1.94503396e-04,-7.18393130e-04],  [-3.09258020e-03,5.79850435e-05,-1.18226050e-03]])
intercept_= np.array([-0.0006201,-0.0002349,0.0007245,0.0001305])

#scikit learn predict_proba
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model1 = LogisticRegression()
model1.classes_=np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
model1.coef_= coef_
model1.intercept_= intercept_
predict_proba=model1.predict_proba(test)
print(predict_proba)

#manual computation requires softmax to obtain the same probability estimates
logits = np.dot(test, coef_.T) + intercept_
exp_logits = np.exp(logits)
manual_probabilities = exp_logits / np.sum(exp_logits) # (!!) softmax
print(manual_probabilities) #result match those of model1.predict_proba

#without softmax
probability_no_softmax = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-logits))
print(probability_no_softmax)

#without softmax normalized
probability_no_softmax_norm=probability_no_softmax/np.sum(probability_no_softmax)
print(probability_no_softmax_norm)

Returns
[[0.20073414 0.03771189 0.69806425 0.06348971]] #manual with softmax

[[0.20073414 0.03771189 0.69806425 0.06348971]] #predict_proba 

[[0.59729212 0.21792308 0.83760631 0.31931782]] #without softmax non-normalized

[[0.30286507 0.11050085 0.42471964 0.16191443]] #without softmax normalized


